# Question about Enriched Categories and Functors

Tags: ct.category-theory, adjoint-functors, enriched-category-theory

How would one describe the process of enriching a category C over some monoidal category D? Is there some functor between them that adds structure to the hom-sets?

Answer (score 7):

While [Paul's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/227256/49) is correct, it is also possible to start with an ordinary category $C$ and "enrich it" by adding <strike>structure</strike> [stuff](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/227201/question-about-enriched-categories-and-functors#comment561092_227256).  One sort of tautological way to do this is to specify a $V$-enriched category $\hat{C}$ whose underlying ordinary category (in the sense mentioned by [Todd](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/227201/question-about-enriched-categories-and-functors#comment561025_227256)) is isomorphic (or equivalent) to $C$.  A more interesting way is to specify a 2-variable adjunction $V\times C\to C$ with some natural "associativity" conditions (see e.g. Def. 14.3 [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0610194)); this yields not just any enrichment of $C$ but one that is tensored and cotensored.

Answer (score 6):

The question is mis-conceived.

(In any other disciplines, [much less naive questions than this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/227032/submodule-of-module-over-polynomial-ring) are closed rapidly and dismissively, but I am opposed to this practice.)

An enriched category is not a category to which extra structure has been added (and certainly not by a functor), indeed *it need not be a category at all*.

A **$\mathbb{V}$-enriched category** $\mathcal C$ has a collection of objects, just as an ordinary category does, though for clarity I am going to call them **vertices**.  However, instead of a **set** ${\mathcal C}(X,Y)$ of morphisms between any two vertices, it has an **object** of them, where this object belongs to the enriching category $\mathbb V$. As [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/enriched+category) or numerous textbooks will explain, $\mathbb V$ has to be a **monoidal category**, whose tensor product and unit provide composition and identities in $\mathcal C$.

Probably you are imagining that $\mathbb V$ is a category of vector spaces or topological spaces or something else that has "underlying sets".

Forget that and think of something else, like this:

Let ${\mathbb V}={\mathbb R}^+$, where $a\to b$ iff $a\geq b$, the tensor product is $+$ and the unit is $0$.

**Please** work out the characterisation of this example as a valuable exercise for yourself before you look it up in [this famous paper](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/1/tr1abs.html).

Comment: While I agree with the main spirit of this post, it should be mentioned that there is a standard "underlying ordinary category" of a $V$-enriched category $C$, obtained by applying the monoidal functor $\hom(I, -): V \to \text{Set}$ to the hom-objects where $I$ is the monoidal unit.  Kelly in his famous treatise denotes this as $C_o$ (the "o" for "ordinary").

Comment: @Todd, OK, I didn't think of that, but in the example that I give the "underlying category" is discrete and so not very interesting.

Comment: No, actually it's a preorder (it need not be true that $\hom(x, y) = 0$ implies $x = y$ in these generalized you-know-whats).

Comment: In general, the forgetful functor Todd Trimble describes is not faithful; in nLab terminology, this means that being an enriched category is not extra structure on a category, but "extra stuff." Things are a bit better if $\text{Hom}(I, -)$ is faithful (which is not the case in Paul Taylor's example).

Comment: Another dramatic example of the phenomenon that Qiaochu is referring to is where $V$ is the monoidal category of chain complexes (of say vector spaces over a field). Here the monoidal unit is concentrated in degree 0, and so the forgetful functor from $V$-categories to ordinary categories forgets almost everything, and it would be inappropriate to view $V$-categories as ordinary categories endowed with extra structure -- you'd really have to view the 'extra' as extra 'stuff' which got ignored, in the technical sense of https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/stuff,+structure,+property.